# Password Change from one location and Security

Tags: asp.net, security, change-password

I am creating an asp.net web application with "Remember Me" option during Login and it has an Edit Profile module where users can change their passwords. Here is the scenario.

1. I logged into the website from Machine A clicking "Remember Me". So I am logged in and since a persistent cookie is created I dont need to login the next time
   until my forms authentication times out.
2. I logged into the website from Machine B using the same account details I used above and from this machine, I changed my password.  In this case How can I make the user in Machine A to login again? (Since my credentials have changed). The same scenario can happen if someone gets any user's credential and uses the application.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You have to save the last credentials modification date in your database.

When a user try to consult a page of your website, you have to check the date specified in the cookie.

You can also make an AJAX system that verify each minute if any changes are done and, in that case, verify the validity of the credentials.

If the latest date is the "last credentials modification", then delete the cookie and ask the user to log by himself.

Comment: This is OK "When a user try to log to your website" . But in my scenario, the user is already logged in and working in Machine A (say a Hacker). Then from my machine say Machine B  I am changing my password.

Comment: Updated answer in 2 minutes